# Slideshow placeholder with superimposed arrow images will not resize in relation to screen size

Tags: html, css

I have overlaid previous and next arrows on an image placeholder for a slideshow, but I cannot get the placeholder to resize in relation to the screen size. I thought the solution would be as simple as nesting the placeholder in another div and using CSS margins, percentages, etc., but this does not seem to work. My code is below, with CSS styles in the header for convenience, and it should look like the image (see link below), but the buttons have to be working and not just for show - hence the overlaid arrows. Any help would be appreciated.

[Slideshow Placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3qST.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Slideshow Image Placeholder with Direction Arrows</title>

<style>
    #placeholder-image-container {
        position: relative:
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }   

    #placeholder-image {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #left {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 300px;     
    }

    #right {
        position: absolute;
        left: 884px;
        top: 300px;     
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="slideshow-placeholder-container">
    <img src="placeholder-image.jpg" id="coutts" />
    <a href="#"><img src="left-pointer.jpg" id="left" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="right-pointer.jpg" id="right" /></a>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```